# Trying to make calculation with gdal_calc.py?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, rgdal, gdal2tiles

I have a tif image that I'm trying to run gdal_calc.py.
In the source file the values are between 1,118-9,704 and I want to divide all the values by 10,000 to get results between 0-1.

This is the command I run:

```
gdal_calc.py --type=Float32 -A C:\z\input.tif --outfile=C:\z\output.tif --calc="A/10000"
```

The problem is that the output is not working, it seems that it does not know how to get decimal numbers.

I display the output in ArcMap software

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The division in gdal is an integer division by default. You can change this behaviour by dividing with a float. In you case, simply replace 10000 by 10000.0

```
gdal_calc.py --type=Float32 -A C:\z\input.tif --outfile=C:\z\output.tif --calc="A/10000.0"
```

Note that storing in 16bit integer is more efficient than float 32, so I should think twice before running this type of conversion.